SageMaker Canvas instance usage and training history
I have been exploring AWS SageMaker Canvas this month, building models and getting predictions mostly by batch. I want to get the hours spent on training and instance used in order to better understand the cost of the service usage but I can't find them anywhere.
In AWS Cost Explorer, I only have the instance used and usage type like "EUC1-Train, EUC1-AsyncInf, ..."
Is there a way to find more details about the service usage by model and training hours, etc?

You can use "cost allocation tags" to track your cost at more detailed level.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html
On SageMaker Canvas, you can use the cost allocation tags at the user profile level.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/canvas-manage-cost.html
